# Role built for the platform is incompatible with windows azure compute emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-emulator

Im trying to run a 32 bit appication on windows azure emulator 
I changed the project platfrom using configuration manager. but then im getting this error:

> Cannot start debugging. The Role built for the platform is
>   incompatible with windows azure compute emulator. On this system, the
>   compute emulator only supports AnyCPU and x64.

Im running vs2012 in administrator mode. I also followed this tutorial: [Link](http://azure.codegrains.com/2014/03/enable-32-bit-mode-for-application-web.html)